# show content from right to left in web (html and css)

Tags: html, css

I want to show the content in my website from right to left, I'm trying using Flex from bootstrap but still doesn't work, did javascript library like jquery needed to show content from right to left?

this is the look I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTth1.png)

this is my web look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwCFS.png)

this is myhtml

```
    <div class="container">
    @foreach ($books as $book)

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center " style="width:150px; direction:rtl">
        <div class="card bg-info mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="{{ asset("img/books/$book->gambar") }}" width="150" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $book->judul }}</h5>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why would `float: left` make the content go from right to left?

Comment: @Sean I misunderstood the question. I thought the intent was to make a horizontally scrollable list of the child elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a [`.flex-row-reverse` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction) that can be used to change the direction of a flex row. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
    @foreach ($books as $book)
      <div class="justify-content-center" style="width:150px; direction:rtl">
        <div class="card bg-info mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="{{ asset('img/books/$book->gambar') }}" width="150" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $book->judul }}</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >detail</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-row-reverse doesn't work, but `float : left` work, thank you myfriend